# Scaling the UIView resets rotation

Tags: ios, swift, cgaffinetransform

I am using this code to scale the view :

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
```

It scales the view perfectly, But problem is that:

If I rotate the view first and then scale it, in this case also scaling works as required but it resets the rotation.

It should not reset the rotation.

Comment: i think you scaling only x here, try for both "x" and "y"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a transform that only has a scale and you are then applying just that scale to the view.

You want to apply the scale transform to the existing transform.

```
view.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: 2, y: 2)
```